# What is the correct JSON to pass to an action which accepts a collection of KeyValuePairs?

Tags: json, json.net, odata, asp.net-web-api

I created an action like this:

```
ActionConfiguration setVisualParameter = builder.Entity<CSensor>().Action("SetVisualParameter");
setVisualParameter.CollectionParameter<KeyValuePair<string,int>>("VisualParameter");
```

Now I try to pass this parameter in fiddler:

```
POST ~/odata/Sensors(5)\SetVisualParameter HTTP/1.1
'
'
'

{"VisualParameter":{"Key":"Hello","Value":1},{"Key":"Hello2","Value":2}}
```

to the action and I always get the error:

```
"Invalid JSON. A comma character ',' was expected in scope 'Object'. Every two elements in an array and properties of an object must be separated by commas."
```

How can I pass it?

Comment: Try {"VisualParameter":[{"Key":"Hello","Value":1},{"Key":"Hello2","Value":2}]}

Answer (score 3):

If `VisualParameter` is supposed to be a collection (array) of objects, then you must enclose it in square brackets to make it valid JSON:

```
{
    "VisualParameter": 
    [
        {
            "Key": "Hello",
            "Value": 1
        },
        {
            "Key": "Hello2",
            "Value": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to check whether your JSON is valid.